# I am getting internal error 500 instead of 404 in mongoose when using res.json()

Tags: node.js, api

```
import express from 'express'
import asyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import Product from '../models/productModel.js'
const router = express.Router() 

router.get('/',asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({})

    res.json(products)
}))

router.get('/:id',asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).exec()
    
if(product)
{
    res.json(product)
}
else{
    res.status(404).json({message: 'Not found'})
}
}))

export default router
```

Rest code is working. But when I intentionally put the wrong id, error 404 is not displayed.
The Error part is this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because you pass an `id`-value to mongoose that cannot be cast to `ObjectId`, hence the error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value". You can prevent passing invalid object-ids using the following check and handle this case accordingly, e.g.:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

router.get('/:id',asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  if( !mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id) ) {
    return res.status(404).json({message: 'Not found'});
  }
  // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: if i am doing what you had written. For invalid ids i m still getting same error..and for valid ids i am getting my response as 404

Comment: I've updated my code, as I didn't use `req.params.id` - can you try again?

Comment: Okay it has been updated. Code is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use exec() method. Refer to [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById)

```
const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).exec()
```

Comment: getting the same error.. let me add exec() in the question

Comment: can you console.log(product)?

Comment: I am putting console.log(product) in if section but its not showing. Is my code not going inside the if statement?

Comment: The problem is that the id cannot be cast to ObjectId in the first place, it has nothing to do with `.exec()` - see my answer ...